# Create a directory

Tags: c

I am trying to create a directory using the following code. It compiles, but it does not create a directory. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int main(void)
{
  const char base[] = "filename";
  char filename [ FILENAME_MAX ];
  int number = 42;
  sprintf(filename, "%s/%d", base, number);
  printf("filename = \"%s\"\n", filename);
  mkdir (filename, S_IRWXU);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not catch return code of mkdir?  linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir

Comment: Check whether `mkdir` returns `-1` and the value of `errno` consequently.

Comment: Indeed. Try asking it why it's not working! `if (mkdir(filename, S_IRWXU) != 0) { perror("mkdir() error"); }`.

Comment: @hari: Please do not post links to `die.net`. This site is a crappy place with outdated information that appears first in google results due to SEO. Use kernel.org - http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mkdir.2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the "filename" directory already exist? `mkdir()` will only create one directory at a time; if the parent directory doesn't exist either, you'll have to create it separately, first.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it fails to create directory because you are trying to create a nested directory and its parent does not exist. [`mkdir`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) cannot create directories recursively. But you can only guess unless you properly check return codes and errors in your program.