# Create a file and its parents directories in c

Tags: c, file, fopen, subdirectory

I didn't find any relevant answer for this question.

I want to create a file and its parent directory at the same time:

example:

```
FILE *fd2 = fopen("test/test", "w+");
```

where test/ doesn't exist.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, create directory "test", then create file "test/test".  I believe directory creation is OS specific,  so specify your OS.

Comment: I work on linux. Isn't there a way to create automatically the directory? @chux

Comment: Not much happens in C automatically.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431725/how-to-create-a-directory-in-user-space-in-a-linux-kernel-module

Comment: You can create the directory part of the path using the code in [How can I create a directory tree in C++/Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675039/how-can-i-create-directory-tree-in-c-linux/675193), which actually has a bilingual answer with code that's both C and C++.  You need the [`dirname()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dirname.html) function to get the directory part of the name.  It will be two separate operations — create the directories, then create the file.

Comment: May find [this interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700185/create-a-directory) as well.

Comment: @chux and that is good thing.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can do it with the following code

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
... 
/* check if directory exist */
struct stat status = { 0 };
if( stat("test", &status) == -1 ) {
  /* create it */
  mkdir( "test", 0700 );
}
/* open file */
FILE *fd2 = fopen("test/test", "w+");
...
```

For the situation when file `test` exists in first `if` statement (`stat` return value is zero), you can also check if this is a file or a directory using macros `S_ISREG` and `S_ISDIR` and field `st_mode` of `stat` struct.